# Two Div's next to each other with "text-overflow: ellipsis; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;"

Tags: html, ellipsis

I got to deep in this problem and can not see the forest out of all the trees around me... but maybe there is a quick solution for this. I work with CSS 3 and cannot add 2 div's in one line with the following condition:
1. DIV dynamic width and cutting text. 
2. DIV next to 1. DIV (inline) with fixed with.

So if the container (sourounding DIV) is 300px. And the 2. DIV is 100px. I expect that the 1. DIV gets a size of 200px (dynamic) and cutting its text if needed.

So this is the code from my side so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .container {
            width: 200px;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
        .info {
            text-overflow: ellipsis;
            overflow: hidden;
            white-space: nowrap;
        }
        .dynamicWidth {

        }
        .staticWidth {
            width: 60px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="dynamicWidth">
            <div>Title element</div>
            <div class="info">Text: This is a text which should be break with 3 dots when it is bigger then its parent div</div>
        </div>
        <div class="staticWidth">BUT</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Unfortunately, all the time the 2. DIV is below the 1. DIV.

Thx for your hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found a fitting solution:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .container {
            border: 1px solid black;
            position: relative;
        }
        .info {
            text-overflow: ellipsis;
            overflow: hidden;
            white-space: nowrap;
        }
        .dynamicWidth {
            margin-right: 30px;
        }
        .staticWidth {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            right: 0;
            width: 30px;
            top: 25%; /*centers the content of this div in middle of height*/
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="dynamicWidth">
            <div>Title element</div>
            <div class="info">Text: This is a text which should be break with 3 dots when it is bigger then its parent div</div>
        </div>
        <div class="staticWidth">BUT</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems:

- Divs generete a box, so theres only one div per line, so you need the display property to change this (see http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp)
- The element with the dynamic width tries to get the space the inner text requires, so it forces the other div in the next line, try using css3 columns (see http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_column-count.asp)